# Can we check system Information through SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012. I use production SQL server located in other country. The performance is quite slow. I have internet with good band width and my system configuration is quite good. I need to check production SQL server's system info through SQL Server. Is it possible?
System Info Like Hard disc memory, RAM, Processor, OS etc..

Answer (score 5):

You can actually find out a great deal about the OS where the SQL Server is installed using queries on selected DMVs.

For example, to get information about the memori config, check the `sys.dm_os_sys_memory`:

```
SELECT total_physical_memory_kb/1024 AS [Physical Memory (MB)], 
       available_physical_memory_kb/1024 AS [Available Memory (MB)], 
       total_page_file_kb/1024 AS [Total Page File (MB)], 
       available_page_file_kb/1024 AS [Available Page File (MB)], 
       system_cache_kb/1024 AS [System Cache (MB)],
       system_memory_state_desc AS [System Memory State]
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_memory WITH (NOLOCK) OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

This and other useful queries can be found at Glen Berry's site:

http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check the Dynamic Management Views: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754.aspx for the first steps.

Another way is to set up a Performance Monitor Data Collector Set (and store the gathered information in SQL Server database).

Answer (score 1):

run  *!!SystemInfo* in your management studio and turn on sqlcmd mode .

Comment: Does this !!SystemInfo give the system info of the machine where the SSMS runs or the system details of remote DB server?